# TypeScript Store Parse Query result

Tags: javascript, typescript, parse-platform

I have following code

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public guests: any[] = [];


  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.apiService.getAllGuestsQuery().find({
      success(results) {
        for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          const object = results[i];
          console.log(object.get('companyName'));
        }
      },
      error(error) {
        console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

The `getAllGuestsQuery` returns a `Parse.Query` object. I would like to store the result in my guests array. E.g. do something like `this.quests = results`
But I cannot access this.guests class variable inside the success method.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public guests: any[] = [];


  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let vm = this;
    this.apiService.getAllGuestsQuery().find({
        func(r){ vm.guests } // will be available
    });
  }
}
```

This is caused because when you pass the {} construct to the find() function a new scope is being created there. If you used the ES6 arrow syntax you could make this better(but a hassle for me to write, you'd have to handle the errors in a totally different manner, preferably promises)

Answer (score 0):

You could try passing a reference to `this` in a separate variable at the beginning of your `ngOnInit()` method. Something like `let that = this;`. Refer to `this` (class instance) via `that` later on in your callback.